# Perl CPAN installation - dependency issue

Tags: linux, perl

All,

I am getting following dependency issue while installing CPAN for perl,

```
>yum install perl-CPAN


---> Package perl-devel.x86_64 4:5.10.1-141.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6 for package: 4:perl-devel-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.166.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
           Requires: glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6
           Installed: glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.i686 (@RHEL_UPDATES_2015)
               glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.3
           Available: glibc-2.12-1.166.el6.i686 (RHEL6_ISO)
               glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6 Error: Package: perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.55-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@RHEL_UPDATES_2015)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6_7.1
           Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6 Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.12-1.166.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
           Requires: glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6
           Installed: glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.i686 (@RHEL_UPDATES_2015)
               glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6_7.3
           Available: glibc-2.12-1.166.el6.i686 (RHEL6_ISO)
               glibc = 2.12-1.166.el6 Error: Package: 1:perl-Digest-SHA-5.47-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@RHEL_UPDATES_2015)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6_7.1
           Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6 Error: Package: 1:perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS-2.2003.0-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@RHEL_UPDATES_2015)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6_7.1
           Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6 Error: Package: perl-Test-Harness-3.17-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@RHEL_UPDATES_2015)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6_7.1
           Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6 Error: Package: 4:perl-devel-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@RHEL_UPDATES_2015)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6_7.1
           Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6 Error: Package: perl-CPAN-1.9402-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@RHEL_UPDATES_2015)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6_7.1
           Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-141.el6 Error: Package: db4-devel-4.7.25-19.el6_6.x86_64 (RHEL6_ISO)
           Requires: db4 = 4.7.25-19.el6_6
           Installed: db4-4.7.25-20.el6_7.i686 (@RHEL_UPDATES_2015)
               db4 = 4.7.25-20.el6_7
           Available: db4-4.7.25-19.el6_6.i686 (RHEL6_ISO)
               db4 = 4.7.25-19.el6_6  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

How to resolve this. Installed perl version is 5.10 and Linux version is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

Comment: I am guessing that some of your packages need to be updated or a different version installed, for example glibc, try to check with rpm -qa | grep glibc

Comment: `**[root@mcscs-pr-labc01 /]# rpm -qa | grep glibc**
    glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
    glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.i686
    glibc-common-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64`

Comment: What happens if you remove  glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 package and try to install it again ? Probably you have 2 different versions installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check required packages if they are 64-bit; i686=32-bit, x86_64=64-bit.
Though I prefer installing latest perlbrew, not system perl, and then necessary modules through cpan. They may be newer than redhat perl ones.